# Bash autocompletion

Tags: bash, kubuntu, auto-completion

When I'm typing in the bash, something is trying to autocomplete my input in a rather weird way, see picture attached.
I'm not pressing tab or something, just trying to type like "describe table" or "select"

What's causing it? How to unmount?

[image: Screenshot #1]

[image: Screenshot #2]

The previous user denies installing any utils of the kind

Comment: This doesn't look like it is bash. Rather seems like some SQL console. Please edit your question give more context. Also your OS details would be interesting.

Comment: Which key is the `smth` key?

Answer (score 1):

There was a gxneur installed, looks like it was the cause of the problem. I removed it from system, and now the bash feels fine while i'm typing, everything looks ok, no doubled letters or anything.

Comment: im sorry but i dont get it ur question or answer can u be more detailed so that it can help others in future thanks
did gxneur service affect ur text string being typed ?

Comment: did gxneur service affect ur text string being typed ? – Sure it did. It made the strings look like on screenshots.